# 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.ControlObjectsVisibility' is obsolete: 'This property is obsoloete in RadAsyncUpload'

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have got this warning:

> 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.ControlObjectsVisibility' is obsolete:
>   'This property is obsoloete in RadAsyncUpload'

I need to get rid of it.

As I have understood, I need to replace

> ControlObjectsVisibility
>   by other property. 
>   Tell my by what to replace?

Answer (score 1):

[ControlObjectsVisibility was used in the old RadUpload control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/upload/how-to/configure-the-ui-of-radupload).

Telerik has deemed it as no longer used in their RadAsyncUpload control.

```
[Description("Gets or sets the value indicating which control objects will be displayed. This property is obsolete in RadAsyncUpload and is not used.")]
[Obsolete("This property is obsolete in RadAsyncUpload")]
public virtual ControlObjectsVisibility ControlObjectsVisibility { get; set; }
```

Based on the error message you provided, it looks like you're using the RadAsyncUpload control and as such, you can remove that line of code.